# Need help in printing records from database

Tags: database, records

I want to print records from db like this.

http://www.imagesup.net/dm-613781138202.png

I have tried for loop and foreach both.

The sample code is:

```
<?php
$str = '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14';
$str2 = (explode(",",$str));
echo '<table border="1">';
foreach ($str2 as $str3)
{
echo '<tr>';
for($i=0;$i<5;$i++)
{
echo '
<td>'.$str3.'</td>
';
}
echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
?>
```

I have tried many others but not getting required result.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
<?php

$str = '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14';
echo '<table>';
$list = explode(",", $str);
$itemsPerRow = 7;

for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($list); $i+=$itemsPerRow)
{
   echo '<tr>';
   for($j = 0; $j < $itemsPerRow; $j++)
   {
      $val = isset($list[$i + $j]) ? $list[$i + $j] : '';
      echo '<td>' . $val . '</td>';
   }
   echo '</tr>'
}
echo '</table>'
?>
```

The above uses two for loops to iterate over the data. The outer loop controls the row, and the inner loop controls the content.

Comment: Thanks for reply...However i am getting an error

Notice: Underfined variables: ItemsperRow in C:\xampp\htdocs\testme.php on line 57

Comment: your code is printing this.
1234567891011121314000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
in a single row

Comment: @SudheerPal Corrected. There are couple of unclosed tags. And I have also altered the loop so that it will not print out so many zero values.

Comment: I want to print records as a grid as shown in image http://www.imagesup.net/dm-613781138202.png

Comment: @SudheerPal Do you need table with 4 rows and 7 columns. or do you want to size it to fit data?

Comment: rows is according to data but column is predefined.
that means columns are set like 5 or 6

Comment: Hello dear...after a modification in your code..its working now.     after replacing dot in place of '+'                             Really thanx a lot.

Comment: @SudheerPal Cool, glad to see its working. I cannot test php code at the moment and hence the obvious typos.

Answer (score 0):

@kami you should replace `+` with `.` like this.

```
<?php

 $str = '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14';
 echo '<table>';
 $list = explode(",", $str);
 $itemsPerRow = 7;

for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($list); $i+=$itemsPerRow)
{
   echo '<tr>';
   for($j = 0; $j < $itemsPerRow; $j++)
     {
    $val = isset($list[$i + $j]) ? $list[$i + $j] : '';
  echo '<td>' .$val. '</td>';
   }
   echo '</tr>';
}
  echo '</table>';
 ?>
```

Comment: You should appreciate by voting up.